# Using SQL commands stored in a table

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a SQL Server stored procedure that returns a simple count of records.

However as part of the query I would like to append some SQL to the WHERE clause that would come from a record in another table. **eg. AND customer_id = '0747'**

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: @user..put your select statement in one variable of type varchar, deaclare another variable and set with where clause by selecting from table and then append them to make a single statement and finally execute

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more? What part of the string you want to append, will come from other table/column?

Comment: Do you *have* to do this for some reason (get criteria from a table) or is there a bigger problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(1000) = 'SELECT * FROM [TableName] WHERE [ColumnName] = Value '
DECLARE @WhereClause nvarchar(1000)

SELECT @WhereClause = [Value] FROM [Table that stores queries] WHERE ID = [Unique Identifier of query]

SET @Query = @Query + @WhereClause

EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: You forgot to put the right part of the `@WhereClause` assignment in quotes. But apart from that: correct.

Comment: I believe quotes are not required as we are selecting a field from table and assigning it to a variable :)

Comment: @AbhishekChaudhary: I am so blind.